# Solution of square root of the square of (-1)

Tags: arithmetic, radicals

What is the result of $$ \sqrt{(-1)^2} ?$$
I see two potential ways of solving this. First, by direct calculation
$$ \sqrt{(-1)^2} = \sqrt{1} = 1. $$
Second, by applying the power rule
$$ \sqrt{(-1)^2} = (-1)^{2^{1/2}} = (-1)^{2/2} = -1. $$

Intuitively, I would say the first approach is correct. However, I did not find any restrictions to the power rule that would rule out the second solution.

Comment: Normal exponent rules don't apply to negative bases. So the first approach is correct.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3219025/why-22-5-isnt-equal-to-2251-10)

Comment: Take a look at this question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3345202/square-root-of-a-product-of-negative-numbers

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Square root of a product of negative numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3345202/square-root-of-a-product-of-negative-numbers)

Comment: Thank you for your answers! My question is answered thoroughly in the thread proposed by @J.W.Tanner .

Comment: I think you meant $2 \cdot 1/2$, not $2^{1/2}$.